# GatsbyJS background image using ACF & WordPress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, advanced-custom-fields, gatsby

I am trying to display a background image using the [gatsby-background-image plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-background-image/?=backg). My code returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'acf' of undefined" at the moment.

I've tried changing my query in all sorts of variations but can't figure out how to get the background image to display. I think the problem might be related to that every page contains that particular ACF field. Some returns null (those I have not used yet) and the rest returns the image. Maybe I need to add some conditional logic in there to cater for when that particular field is empty?

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image';

const IndexPage = (props) => (
    <Layout >
        <BackgroundImage
            className="masthead"
            fluid={props.data.allWordpressPage.edges.node.acf.banner.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid}
            fadeIn
        >
            <div className="black-overlay">
                <div className="content-box">
                    <h1>This is where my h1 tag goes</h1>
                    <h2>This is my sub head</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </BackgroundImage>
    </Layout >
)

export default IndexPage

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allWordpressPage {
      edges {
        node {
          acf {
            banner {
              localFile {
                childImageSharp {
                  fluid(maxWidth: 1800) {
                    ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                  }
                }
              }
            } 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Here is what my query returns in GraphQL )I've edited long URL from tracedSVG and Base64 out):

```
{
  "data": {
    "allWordpressPage": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "acf": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "acf": {
              "banner": {
                "localFile": {
                  "childImageSharp": {
                    "fluid": {
                      "base64": "data:image/jpeg;base64",
                      "tracedSVG": "data:image/svg+xml",
                      "srcWebp": "/static/beb79c2e06df840f0e0578a05fb731fa/685a2/tyler-nix-LH6GBACnq5A-unsplash-scaled.webp",
                      "srcSetWebp": "/static/beb79c2e06df840f0e0578a05fb731fa/b8a88/tyler-nix-LH6GBACnq5A-unsplash-scaled.webp 450w,\n/static/beb79c2e06df840f0e0578a05fb731fa/210c1/tyler-nix-LH6GBACnq5A-unsplash-scaled.webp 900w,\n/static/beb79c2e06df840f0e0578a05fb731fa/685a2/tyler-nix-LH6GBACnq5A-unsplash-scaled.webp 1800w,\n/static/beb79c2e06df840f0e0578a05fb731fa/ab8d3/tyler-nix-LH6GBACnq5A-unsplash-scaled.webp 2560w",
                      "originalImg": "/static/beb79c2e06df840f0e0578a05fb731fa/4a461/tyler-nix-LH6GBACnq5A-unsplash-scaled.jpg",
                      "originalName": "tyler-nix-LH6GBACnq5A-unsplash-scaled.jpg",
                      "presentationWidth": 1800,
                      "presentationHeight": 1200
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "acf": {
              "banner": null
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your thinking is correct: GraphQL will throw an error for the pages where the field is `null`. As you said, you can add a simple if to make sure it's defined!

Comment: If this doesn't work, I can help you debug it if you provide a reproduction repo :)